# Laravel - multiple forms/tables - carry over variable in URL to fill table column

Tags: laravel-5.7

I am quite new to coding and to Laravel (using 5.7). I understood how to create a basic one-page form to populate a table in a database, including relashionship and authentication but I have difficulties reaching the next level.
**The app I want to design will have multiple forms and tables and I can't figure out how to link info collected from the first form to the following one.**

Let's consider a Database with:
- a Clients table (populated thru form page A) ex: one field is a client_id field.
- a Products table (populated thru form page B)
- (ultimately they will be more)

When the user (e.g. an employee of a compagny analyzing clients behavior) is done filling the form page A (URL: /clients, GET method: Clientcontroller@create, view clients.create.blade.php), he/she click Next.

My idea is that the Next button should:
- submit information to the Client table (POST method: Clientscontroller@store)
- and redirect the user to the page B of the form, carrying over the client_id in the URL (URL: /products/{client_id}/create, GET method: Productscontroller@create,  view products.create.blade.php).

In the Product table, I have a client_id column and I have a one to many relashionship between the Clients and Products model.

Upon submission of form B, I would like to retrieve the {client_id} from URL to fill the client_id column of the Product table but I am stuck here. I would appreciate pieces of guidance and advices. For simplification during the learning process, I consider that Clients only buy one product.

**THE MAIN QUESTION IS:
- How to retrieve the {client_id} parameter from the URL of the products.create.blade.php view to inject it onto the client view (already tried a lot of thing from answer to similar questions in stackoverflow)
ALSO:
- Am I using the right approach? Any suggestions/advices?**

EXTRA QUESTION a bit out of the scope:
- Any hint on how implement add/remove fields for products?

***WEB ROUTES FILE:***

```
> <?php
>     Route::get('/', 'PagesController@welcome')->name('welcome');
>     Auth::routes();
>     //ROUTES FOR CLIENT
>     Route::resource('clients','ClientsController');
>     //ROUTES FOR PRODUCT (please note the {client_id} parameter)
>     Route::get('/products/{client_id}/create', 'ProductsController@create')->name('products.create');
>     Route::post('/products/{client_id}', 'ProductsController@store')->name('products.store');
>     //not sure if it should be Route::post('/products', 'ProductsController@store')->name('products.store');
```

***CLIENTS CONTROLLER:***

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Client; //THIS IS THE CLIENT MODEL
use App\User; ////THIS IS THE USER MODEL
class ClientsController extends Controller
{
    AUTH
    public function __construct()
            {
                $this->middleware('auth');
            }

    //INDEX (CLIENT)
    public function index()
        {
            //my code here
        }

    //CREATE (CLIENT)
    public function create()
        {
            $datas=[
            'controllermethod' => 'ClientsController@store',
            'client_id_field' => [
                        'input_type_l' => 'textinput',
                        'input_name_l' => 'client_id', //this what i am carrying over in URL
                        'input_label_l' => 'Client ID :',
                        'input_placeholder_l' => 'XXXXX',
                        'input_default_l' => ''
                ],
            'client_info_1_field' => [
                        'input_type_l' => 'textinput',
                        'input_name_l' => 'client_info_1'
                        'input_label_l' => 'Client Info 1 :',
                        'input_placeholder_l' => 'XXXXX',
                        'input_default_l' => ''
                ],
            'client_info_2_field' => [
                        'input_type_l' => 'textinput',
                        'input_name_l' => 'client_info_2'
                        'input_label_l' => 'Client Info 2 :',
                        'input_placeholder_l' => 'XXXXX',
                        'input_default_l' => ''
                ]
                    ],
        return view ('clients.create')->with($datas);
        }

    //STORE (CLIENT)
    public function store(Request $request)
            {
                $this->validate($request, [
                        'client_id' => 'required',
                ]);

                $client = new Client;
                $client->client_id = $request->input('client_id');
                $client->client_info_1 = $request->input('client_info_1');
                $client->client_info_2 = $request->input('client_info_2');
                $client->user_id = auth()->user()->id; //one to many relashionship betw user/client models
                $client->save();

            //          
            //this is how I inject the {client_id} parameter onto the URL
            //this works, the products.create view is displayed, the URL contain the client_id from formA entered by the user
            $client_id = $request->client_id;
            return redirect("/products/$client_id/create")->with('client_id', $client_id)
                                       ->with('success','New client record created');

    //SHOW/DESTROY/EDIT/UPDATE FUNCTIONS....all this work
```

***PRODUCTS CONTROLLER = THAT's WERE I AM STUCK + NOT SURE IF IT's THE RIGHT APPROACH***

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
//note sure if I need that
//use Illuminate\Routing\Route;
use App\Product;
use App\Client;
use App\User;

class ProductsController extends Controller
{   
        //AUTH
    public function __construct()
            {
                $this->middleware('auth');
            }

    //INDEX (PRODUCT)
        public function index()
        {
            //no code so far
        }

    //INDEX (PRODUCT)
    public function create()
        {
            $datas=[
                    'controllermethod' => 'ProductsController@store',
                //planning of having dynamic add/remove products fields but let's keep it simple (1 client -> 1 product)
            'product_id_field' => [
                        'input_type_l' => 'textinput',
                        'input_name_l' => 'product_id',
                        'input_label_l' => 'Date of cancer diagnosis :',
                        'input_default_l' => ''
                ],
            'product_info_1_field' => [
                        'input_type_l' => 'textinput',
                        'input_name_l' => 'product_info_1'
                        'input_label_l' => 'Product Info 1 :',
                        'input_placeholder_l' => 'XXXXX',
                        'input_default_l' => ''
                ],
            'product_info_2_field' => [
                        'input_type_l' => 'textinput',
                        'input_name_l' => 'product_info_2'
                        'input_label_l' => 'Product Info 2 :',
                        'input_placeholder_l' => 'XXXXX',
                        'input_default_l' => ''
                ]
                    ],
        //Below, I am not sure I should do that
        return view ('products.create')->with($datas);
        }

    // STORE (PRODUCT) = THAT's WHERE I AM STUCK
    // everything works except that the client_id column in the products table stays empty or filled with crap

    public function store(Request $request)
        {

        //NOT SURE WHAT TO DO HERE TO RETRIEVE THE {client_id} from the "/products/$client_id/create" ...
    //TO FURTHER INJECT IT AS A VALUE IN THE client_id COLUMN OF THE PRODUCT TABLE
    //I KNOW IT's CRAP, but I TRIED THINGS ALONG THOSE LINES:   
    //return $client_id;
        //$client_id = request()->route()->paremeters('client_id');
        //$client_id = request()->route('client_id');
        //$client_id = $request->client_id;
    //$client_id = url('client_id');


        $product = new Diagnosis;
        $product->product_id = $request->input('product_id');
        $product->product_info_1 = $request->input('product_info_1');
        $product->product_info_2 = $request->input('product_info_2');
        $product->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    //I KNOW IT's CRAP, but I TRIED THINGS ALONG THOSE LINES:        
    //$diagnosis->client_id =  $client_id; //NB: if I write $diagnosis->client_id =  'whatever'; it works
        $diagnosis->save();

        //redirect to client.index view
    return redirect('/clients')->with('success','New patient diagnosis (-es) created'); 

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

our solution will start by looking to this route :

```
Route::get('/products/{client_id}/create','ProductsController@create')->name('products.create');
```

this is the route that contains your client_id that we want to retrieve, and since this value is on the link, we can use the Request object to access to it!

like i said, the $request object already contains the client_id value, so what we need is to retrieve it and send it as a parameter to the view using the with function, so basically your ProductsController@create will be like this :

```
public function create(Request $request) 
{
  // all your code ... 
  return view ('products.create')->with("data",$datas)->with("client_id",$request->client_id);
}
```

so now, we access this value from our view right ? the idea is to add this value as a hidden input on the product form! ( something like this )

```
<form>
  <!-- other inputs .... -->
  <input type="hidden" value="{{$client_id}}" name="client_id" />
</form>
```

after submitting the form, this route will be called :

```
Route::post('/products/{client_id}', 'ProductsController@store')->name('products.store');
```

since the client_id will be sent through the form and not using the link, it would be better if you change your route to

```
Route::post('/products', 'ProductsController@store')->name('products.store');
```

now, we can have access to our value on the store function just by using

```
$client_id = $request->input('client_id')
```

Comment: FYI: Just before you answered, I noticed that I can access client_id in the view just by using {{ Request::segment(2) }}. I now understand that I can use this as value in the hidden input as well. For simplification, I wanted to use this directly in the controller like this: $products->client_id = Request::segment(2); but i get a Non-static should not be called statically" error.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution which works too:

ROUTES:

```
Route::get('/products/{client_id}/create', 'ProductsController@create')-name('products.create');
Route::post('/products', 'ProductsController@store')->name('products.store');
```

PRODUCTS CONTROLLER CREATE FUNCTION:

```
public function create() //keep as in the original question
{
  // all your code ... 
  return view ('products.create')->with("data",$datas)->with("client_id",$request->client_id);
}
```

IN THE VIEW:

```
<form>
  <!-- other inputs .... -->
  <input type="hidden" value="{{Request::segment(2)}}" name="client_id" /> //access the URL segmment 2 which correspond to the client_id
</form>
```

IN THE PRODUCTS CONTROLLER STORE FUNCTION:

```
$client_id = $request->input('client_id')
```

*It would have be nice to use the Request::segment(2) directly in the store function like this but this triggers a "Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::segment() should not be called statically" error that I have not been able to resolve. I don't need an answer to that, however **an hint would be appreciated anyway**. Maybe I'll post a new question if this has not been resolved already.*